# Drag parent starting from its iframe child

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, drag-and-drop, draggable

I've something like this

```
<div draggable="true">
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ?fs=1&amp;feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
</iframe>
</div>
```

and I want to be able to drag the entire div when I start the drag by clicking anywhere on the div including the iframe. However the iframe doesn't cascade the event. I also want to keep the interactions with the youtube video possible (play, fullscreen, etc).

Does anyone have any idea how to do this with html/css/js/jQuery?

Comment: wow, didn't realize untill now that theres a "draggable" attribute in html5

Comment: clicked on the link, you suck

Comment: @GregGuida: I clicked on the link because you mentioned it, you suck ;)

Answer (score 0):

here you have a near example you want....just fix it a little

```
#dra
{
    width:560px;
    height:315px;
    border:1px solid green;
    cursor:pointer;

}

#dra:hover iframe
{
    z-index:-1;position:absolute;
}
```

```
<div id="dra"><iframe  width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/T6s3d2wdXVg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div> 
<script>
$( "#dra" ).draggable({stop: function() {

                $( "iframe" ).css('z-index','0');
            }});

</script>
```